# CUDA __syncthreads() method before global memory operation

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a problem with using the __syncthreads() method. I have this code:

```
__global__ void kernel(float *v1_out, float *v2_out, unsigned int dim){

     int tid = threadIdx.x;
     float v1[N], v2[M]; 

     if(tid < dim){  
        // -- Do some computations on v1 and v2 ... 
        // ... then syncthreads()
        __syncthreads();

       // -- Copy the results into global memory
       for(unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++)
           v1_out[j + tid*N] = v1[j];
       for(unsigned int j = 0; j < M; j++)
           v2_out[j + tid*M] = v2[j];
     }
  }
```

Unfortunately this code gives me incorrect results when I read them from the host, as if the synchronization barrier did not work. However if I write the vectors v1[N] and v2[M] in dummy vectors, say v1_temp[N] and v2_temp[M], and then write these ones to the global memory, the kernel gives me the correct results. The "working" code is:

```
__global__ void kernel(float *v1_out, float *v2_out, unsigned int dim){

     int tid = threadIdx.x;
     float v1[N], v2[M], v1_temp[N], v2_temp[M]; 

     if(tid < dim){  
        // -- Do some computations on v1 and v2 ... 
       // ... then syncthreads()
       __syncthreads();

       // -- Fill the dummy vectors
       for(unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++)
           v1_temp[j] = v1[j];
       for(unsigned int j = 0; j < M; j++)
           v2_temp[j] = v2[j];

       // -- Copy the results into global memory
       for(unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++)
           v1_out[j + tid*N] = v1_temp[j];
       for(unsigned int j = 0; j < M; j++)
           v2_out[j + tid*M] = v2_temp[j];
     }
  }
```

I'm launching only one block, and from what I now __syncthreads() should ensure that all the threads in the block have executed the instructions before it. Now I can't figure out the differences in the behavior of the two kernels and why I need to read the data before writing it to the global memory, can someone explain me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically invoking Undefined Behaviour in your kernel—the intrinsic `__syncthreads()` synchronises *all threads in a block;* normally, execution can only proceed once all threads in the block reach it. However, you have it under a conditional which can succeed for some threads and fail for others. So not all threads are reaching the `__syncthreads()`.

You should move it out of the conditional. That is, close the conditional before, synchronise, and open it again:

```
 if(tid < dim){  
    // -- Do some computations on v1 and v2 ... 
 }

 __syncthreads();

 if(tid < dim) {
   // -- Copy the results into global memory
   for(unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++)
       v1_out[j + tid*N] = v1[j];
   for(unsigned int j = 0; j < M; j++)
       v2_out[j + tid*M] = v2[j];
 }
```

Comment: You're right, my bad, thanks very much for the very clear explanation.